# removing new line characters in csv file from inside columns in unix

Tags: shell, csv, unix, awk, newline

Sample input Data::

```text
cat test.csv
234,aa,bb,cc,30,dd

22,cc,

ff,dd,

40,gg

pxy,aa,,cc,

40

,dd
```

Required output ::

```text
cat test_new.csv
234,aa,bb,cc,30,dd

22,cc,ff,dd,40,gg

pxy,aa,,cc,40,dd
```

I tried various `awk` and `sed` commands, nothing seems to be working out.

eg:: `awk 'NR == 1{ printf $0; next } { printf "%s%s", (/^[0-9]+,/? ORS : ""), $0 } END{ print "" }'`

Above `awk` looks only for numeric characters with "," , but this will create extra line if numeric comes in a column with new line character.

Input file contains Control M characters, that I'm already removing using dos2unix

Comment: Hi I'm getting new line characters in between columns of a csv file. Is there a way to remove new line characters inside columns as well in unix CSV file. tried this AWK command awk 'NR == 1{ printf $0; next } { printf "%s%s", (/^[0-9]+,/? ORS : ""), $0 } END{ print "" }'   , this works 99 % good, but cannot handle numbers that comes in file with new line character in between columns, and create a new line for same

Comment: So, you basically want to replace each sequence _<comma><newline>_ by just a comma? Did you consider trying `sed`?

Comment: its not just replacing comma and newline with just a comma , its like replacing new line characters inside two commas. and this should not impact line formatting as well. this would be reading a CSV file  which is having CLOB columns inside , and in those CLOB columns we have new line characters to be handled

Comment: But isn't this equivalent to what I said? Replacing comma-newline is eqivalent to removing those newlines which follow a comma, and at least for your input, this would provide exactly the output you are requesting.

Comment: i provided a sample data, but in actual data , we might not have comma with the new line all the time. take this as second or third column is a clob column in excel, where we have a paragraph with a lot of new line characters without comma. when we read this file in csv format. it shows one single line splitted in 8-10 lines

Comment: I see the point, but then I don't quite understand how you can recognize, when a line for output is ready to be completed. Are you sure that your input is **valid** CSV? I thought that in valid CSV, multiline fields have to be quoted. If you are sure that this is syntactically correct CSV, you could use a programming language which comes with a CSV parser (I'm using Ruby for this), and read the file, and then you loop over each field and simply remove the newline characters, and finally you write out the updated CSV line.

Comment: I just made a quick experiment: When I export multi-line fields with Excel, they **are** enclosed in quotes, so I would say that your input is not valid CSV.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and look at some other questions that have been upvoted and answered to see how to format your code blocks and sample input/output, then run `cat -v` instead of just `cat` on your input and expectd output files and post the output of THAT in your question so we can see the "Control Ms" (obviously do that BEFORE running `dos2unix` on your file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding "Input file contains Control M characters, that i'm already removing using dos2unix" - that's probably making your life harder. There's a good chance that the "newline"s within a line are just `LF`s while the record endings are `CRLF` and so by removing the `CR`s we can no longer simply set the awk `RS` to `CRLF` and then remove any `LF`s remaining in the record.

If your file was exported from Excel as you say in the comments under your question then, whether the fields are quoted or not, it'll use `CRLF` at the end of each record, and `LF` alone within each field which looks like this if you just don't run `dos2unix` on it:

```
$ cat -v test.csv
234,aa,bb,cc,30,dd^M
22,cc,
ff,dd,
40,gg^M
pxy,aa,,cc,
40
,dd^M
```

so then using any awk:

```
$ awk -v ORS= '{sub(/\r$/,"\n")} 1' test.csv
234,aa,bb,cc,30,dd
22,cc,ff,dd,40,gg
pxy,aa,,cc,40,dd
```

or, if you prefer, using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='\r\n' '{gsub(/\n/,"")} 1' test.csv
234,aa,bb,cc,30,dd
22,cc,ff,dd,40,gg
pxy,aa,,cc,40,dd
```

For more information on parsing CSV with awk see [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Regarding your original script - never use `printf $0`, always use `printf "%s", $0` instead since the former will fail when `$0` contains any printf formatting chars such as `%s`:

```
$ echo 'a%sb' | awk '{printf "%s", $0}'
a%sb$

$ echo 'a%sb' | awk '{printf $0}'
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
        `a%sb'
          ^ ran out for this one
$
```

That applies to using `printf` on all input data.

Comment: thanks for the info Ed, this worked for me awk -v ORS= '{sub(/\r$/,"\n")} 1'

Comment: wanted to know, in case  same input file doesn't have control M characters in it, will this same command will work fine  ?

Comment: You're welcome. No, it's specifically using control Ms (aka CRs aka `\r`s) to separate `LF`s (aka `\n`s) that occur at the end of a record (`CRLF`) from those that occur mid-record (`LF` alone). If you don't have `CR`s then you need a completely different solution that either relies on `LF`s only appearing in quoted fields or  knowing in advance how many fields should be present on each line.

Comment: tried the same awk command on a different file , that have '"' and '-' in between the file columns and starting of the file. somehow data is not getting sorted properly there

Comment: Sorry, I don;t know what that means, ask a new question and include those cases in the sample input/output.

Comment: HI Ed Mortan, can you help me out on the above shared concern. Raised a new question for same as  :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70875550/removing-new-line-r-n-and-m-characters-in-all-column-except-last-one-in-un